# calculate checksum hex in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, ascii, checksum

I want to calculate checksum. The process I want to do like below;

Step-1

```
a="10F8000041303131303030353000000000000000"
```

Step-2

```
10+F8+00+00+41+30+31+31+30+30+30+35+30+00+00+00+00+00+00+00 = D0
```

Step-3

```
~D0 = 2F -> 2F + 1 = 30
```

**I tried that;**

```
def calc_checksum_two(s):        
return '%2X' % (-(sum(ord(c) for c in s) % 256) & 0xFF)
print(calc_checksum_two(a))
```

**Result;**

```
3D
```

Comment: `sum(ord(c) for c in s)` doesn't look right to me. If s is "10F800", this gives you ord("1") + ord("0") + ord("F") + ord("8") + ord("0") + ord("0"). I don't think that's even close to what you want to be doing.

Comment: so how can I sum byte to byte like "10+F8+00+..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)] # ['10', 'F8', '00', ...
c = [int(i, 16) for i in b] # [16, 248, 0, ...
d = 256 - sum(c) % 256 # 0x30
e = hex(d)[2:] # '30'
```

Comment: e=hex(d) 
print(e) 

Result; 0x30 

Thank you Jhon :)

Comment: okay I recently tried to use this function and the checksum I got was incorrect but maybe I misunderstood its usage -- ```ChkSum = hex(sum(c))``` gave me the checksum of the raw values though so basically changed line d -- commenting on this in case someone else stumbles across this and needs just the raw checksum instead of the augmented one

Answer (score 1):

with `s="10F8000041303131303030353000000000000000`, `sum(ord(c) for c in s)` will sum each ord value of each character. This will sums `[ord('1'), ord('0'), ord('F'), ...]`. This is not what you wanted.

to build array of bytes from that string you should instead using:

```
[ a[i:i+2]] for i in range(0, len(a), 2) ]
```

this will create an array like this: `['10', 'F8', '00', ...]`

Then to convert string hex/base16 to integer use `int(hex_string,16)`

That should do it, but here is the function

```
def calc_checksum_two(a):
    return hex(((sum(int(a[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0, len(a), 2))%0x100)^0xFF)+1)[2:]
```